# How to get the order id that the customer canceled with the hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have another API inside plugin for making another order in a website so I want when the customer cancel the woocommerce order I've to canel also the other website order, I'll have the order id of woocommerce and the order id of the other website in `wp_post_meta`

**I just want to know how to get the order id that customer canceled to call the order id and the other one to cancel both**

```
function cancel_SP_order(){

// how to get the order id cancelation with the hook 
get_post_meta() ..... // for example 

// I get $order_id from wp_post_meta which has the other order id 

// I cancel the other 

}
add_action('woocommerce_cancelled_order','cancel_SP_order');
```

if there's a better way for sure I welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for you, the hook itself passes the $order_id.You can access it like this:

```
function cancel_SP_order( $order_id ){

// I get $order_id passed by the hook to use directly.

// I cancel the other 

}
add_action('woocommerce_cancelled_order','cancel_SP_order', 10, 1);
```

The first parameter after your function name ('10') is the priority in which your function will run. The second one, '1', is the number of parameters passed from the hook to the function. In this case it is just '1', the order ID that you need.

Let me know if you need more help?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, but when I create order using php and execute the functionm it executes yes but it doesn't process any info and I get bunch of warning errors. 

when I create it manually as a test I don't get the function executed.

Comment: sorry the hook is 'woocommerce_new_order'

Comment: Hey @Steve I don't understand, do you need more help, with another hook, or did you figure it out :)

Comment: for some reason when I write the order id manullay I get the data normally 
 `$order =    wc_get_order("1798"); // it works`
`$order =    wc_get_order($order_id); // doesn't work`  
 the order id without `#` I cast to string but still doesn't work and yes I get the order id correctly.

Comment: or the issue not in passing be value or ref, I use `add_action('get_footer', 'create_vip_order');` for creating order then `add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'SP_Wc', 10, 1);` which has `$order =    wc_get_order($order_id); // doesn't work` I mean inside but the data doesn't work when the first function executed but with the second reload I get the data normally.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is not in the order_id not in wc_get_order, which should always return an order with that ID. I think the issue could be connected to using get_footer (that doesn't seem right) and triggering an order creation from there, which is unusual. That would also generate a new order on every page load which is not what you probably want.

Comment: the idea for example I created order #10 then I called this function `$order =    wc_get_order($order_id);` after creating the order at once I don't get the data of the order but it runs, but when I create another orders #11, #12 etc.. then I called  `$order =    wc_get_order($order_id);` with the order number #10 I get the data normally!

Comment: The only way that would make sense is if you had a timing issue, somehow calling the order before it got a chance to finish getting created. Creating an order from get_footer still seems to me like a bad idea.

Comment: `add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'SP_Wc', 10, 1)` I already call the function with the hook, I made `sleep(2)` in the beginning of the function but still can't get but when I get the previous order id data it prints normally.